# Finding movies and actors within 2 hops of the "Cloud Atlas"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I understand that it's a variation of the "Bacon" problem, so I've attempted a to change the "Bacon" code a little:

```
MATCH (Cloud Atlas {name:"Cloud Atlas"})-[*2]-(hollywood)
RETURN DISTINCT Hollywood
```

However, this returns only names of actors, but I need names of the films as well.

I've also tried this:

```
MATCH (people:Person, m:Movie)-[*2]-(:Movie {title: "Cloud Atlas"}) RETURN people.name,m.title
```

but it gives an error.

I don't have any previous experience with the program outside of this assignment, so I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong :( Any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> MATCH (:Movie {title:"Cloud Atlas"})-[*2]-(hollywood) RETURN DISTINCT
> hollywood

does indeed match the movies and actors (any type of node actually). If you inspect all the returned results there will be both `:Movie` and `:Person` nodes